# SwiftUI sheet not animating dismissal on macOS Big Sur

Tags: swift, swiftui, macos-big-sur

I would like the sheet dismissal animated just like the appearance but reversed. I think this is also the standard behavior. You can see it in Xcode for example when you create a new file.

But as you can see it just disappears without animation

[image: Demo]

Here's my code:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var isAnotherViewPresented: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Button(action: {
                isAnotherViewPresented.toggle()
            }, label: {
                Text("Button")
            }).sheet(isPresented: $isAnotherViewPresented, content: {
                AnotherView()
            })
        }
        .frame(width: 500, height: 300, alignment: .center)
    }
}

struct AnotherView: View {

    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }, label: {
                Text("Close")
            })
        }.padding()
    }
}
```

I'm on

- Mac mini (M1, 2020)
- macOS Big Sur 11.1 (20C69)
- Xcode 12.3 (12C33)

But I can reproduce this on a

- Mac mini (2018)
- macOS Big Sur 11.0.1 (20B29)
- Xcode 12.2 (12B45b)

Comment: You need to set a Binding value to AnotherView().

Comment: Can you elaborate? @ElTomato

Comment: Just in case - it works with macOS 10.15.7 as is.

Comment: works with animation in macOS 11.1

Comment: I am on macOS 11.1 @Yodagama

Comment: @LukasWürzburger yeah i tested , and it worked as expected. did you run it in real Mac ?

Comment: Yes, I'm on a brand new Mac mini (M1, 2020) @Yodagama

Comment: but I am using xcode 12.2 !

Comment: I can also reproduce with Xcode 12.2 ... just recently moved to the m1 mac and still had 12.2 installed on my old one. @Yodagama

Comment: I meant i can reproduce the bug on another machine. Not the correct behavior.

Comment: maybe you should rather use a ZStack with combined with an if clause an to fully customise this task.

Comment: @LukasWürzburger how did you solve the problem? Stumbled upon the same issue.

Comment: @cocos2dbeginner I didn't. It's really frustrating. I even offered a bounty on this question, but apparently nobody could answer it. I have the feeling that not a lot of people are actually using SwiftUI on macOS yet.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info. If I find a solution I'll let you know!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally figured out how to do it, in my SwiftUI app it works if I do this while closing the sheet:

```swift
isSheetVisible = false
NSApp.mainWindow?.endSheet(NSApp.keyWindow!)
```

Example:

```swift
struct SheetView: View {
    @Binding var isSheetVisible: Bool

    var body: some View {
        Button("Close") {
            isSheetVisible = false
            NSApp.mainWindow?.endSheet(NSApp.keyWindow!)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Working]

Comment: I hate that this works, but dang does I work.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer:** I had/have the same problem where if I try to dismiss a sheet through a binding, it just disappears instead of having an animation. The below solution worked for me but I am unclear as to why its working.

**Solution**

Apparently the view you "attach" a modal to has an impact on how it transitions from being presented to not. For instance, in your code the sheet is attached to the button view:

```
Button(action: {
  isAnotherViewPresented.toggle()
 }, label: {
   Text("Button")
      // sheet is attached here
 }).sheet(isPresented: $isAnotherViewPresented, content: {
    AnotherView()
})
```

When you call `presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()` in the second view the modal jolts and disappears instead of sliding away. However, if you attach the sheet to the outer `HStack` view, then it works and it slides away as expected:

```
var body: some View {
    HStack {
        Button(action: {
            isAnotherViewPresented.toggle()
        }, label: {
            Text("Button")
        })
    }
    .frame(width: 500, height: 300, alignment: .center)
    .sheet(isPresented: $isAnotherViewPresented, content: {
       AnotherView()
    })
    // sheet is now here
}
```

For me as long as the sheet wasn't attached to the button the animation worked. I don't know why this works but it did for me and hopefully it will for you as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I like this mix:

assuming you have:

```
@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
```

then:

```
presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss() // this updates the binding from .sheet(isPresented: ...) to false
NSApp.mainWindow?.endSheet(NSApp.keyWindow!) // this runs the animation
```