# How to add animation to sheet dismissal

Tags: macos, swiftui

Presenting a modal sheet in SwiftUI MacOS has a nice slide in animation, but when dismissed it just disappear.
I would like to add a slide out animation to the dismissal of the sheet.

Adding the slideout on the content of the sheet obviously doesn’t work, as the content slides out, but the sheet frame remains until dismissed.

I might be missing something obvious here, but how can I add animation to the sheet itself?

```
struct ModalSheet: View {
    @Binding var visible: Bool
    @State var isShowing: Bool = true
    
    var body: some View {
        let s = "Click me to dismiss " + String(isShowing);
        VStack {
            Text(s)
        }
        .frame(width: 200, height: 100, alignment: .center)
        .background(Color.green.opacity(0.5))
        .onTapGesture {
            isShowing.toggle()
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.3) {
                visible.toggle()
            }
        }
        .offset(y: self.isShowing ? 0 : CGFloat(-110)) // <-- this should be on the sheet itself
        .animation(self.isShowing ? .none : .default)
    }
}

struct ModalTestAnimation: View {
    @State var visible: Bool = false;
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Click me")
                .onTapGesture {
                    visible = true
                }
        }
        .frame(width: 250, height: 150)
        .sheet(isPresented: $visible, content: {
            ModalSheet(visible: $visible)
        })
    }
}
```

I did take a look at this, but it doesn’t work for me
[SwiftUI sheet not animating dismissal on macOS Big Sur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65390267/swiftui-sheet-not-animating-dismissal-on-macos-big-sur)

Comment: Sheet appearance and hiding is macOS system feature - it differs from version to version. We cannot control it. If you don't like it then don't use system sheet - write own.